# Select treeview item with item path using C# - Used in Coded UI Testing

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, extension-methods, coded-ui-tests

I need to select items in treeview in Coded UI Test automation. I came up with my own solution. I see some performance issues as it is running slow. Any suggestions on improving the performance?

This one I wrote as extension method that way I can use it inline with Treeview control.

Also, node path is custom with assumption that ">" is not used in any item text. I have given example of node text in Summary

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Selects item in a tree view control. 
    /// Eg nodePath: 2017>Jan>21. This will expand 2017 then Jan and select 21st date in treeview
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parentControl">Tree view control</param>
    /// <param name="nodePath">Path where the item to be selected is located. Parent and child are separated with '>'</param>
    public static void SelectItemInTreeView(this WpfTree parentControl, string nodePath)
    {
        char splitter = '>';
        string[] treePath = nodePath.Split(splitter);

        WpfTreeItem parentNode = null;
        UITestControlCollection childNodes = parentControl.Nodes;
        bool itemSelected = false;
        string root = treePath[0];

        string lastItemInTreePath = treePath[treePath.Length - 1];
        foreach (string pathElement in treePath)
        {
            bool found = false;

            foreach (WpfTreeItem item in childNodes)
            {
                UITestControl itemCheck = item.GetChildren().Where(x => x.ControlType == ControlType.Text && x.Name == pathElement).FirstOrDefault();
                if (itemCheck != null)
                {
                    found = true;
                    WpfTreeItem currentItem = null;

                    if (itemCheck.Name.Equals(lastItemInTreePath))
                    {
                        item.Selected = true;
                        itemSelected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentItem = (parentNode == null) ? new WpfTreeItem(parentControl) : new WpfTreeItem(parentNode);
                        currentItem.TechnologyName = "UIA";
                        currentItem.SearchProperties[WpfTreeItem.PropertyNames.Name] = item.Name;
                        currentItem.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.ExpandWhileSearching);
                        currentItem.Expanded = true;

                        parentNode = currentItem;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found)
            {
                Assert.Fail("Error in Tree view path. Correct your input Treeview path: {0}", nodePath);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!itemSelected)
                {
                    childNodes = parentNode.Nodes;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why re-create the WpfTreeItem in the else block when you already have it as the itemCheck.  You can simply cast it to WpfTreeItem.  Not sure how much that will speed it up, but should see some improvement since it already is found.

Comment: That is because ItemCheck is UITestControl. UITestControl does not have .Nodes method only WpfTree and WpfTreeItem can call .Nodes. Though UITestControl got GetChildren method, it gives all child elements...

Comment: Just change the type is what I'm saying.  You are getting the correct type, just as a base class.  You can downcast it to what you need.